# Filtering by column - multiple pd.arrays

Tags: python

I have multiple Dataframes from the same measurements at different times. Now I want to find correlating measurements (which can be located by a string in one of the columns called abmn). The problem is that I cannot iterate since all datasets have a different length.
Would you know any solution?
example

```
df1 
| res | abmn   |
| 3   | 1234   |
| 0   | 1245   |
| 2   | 1256   |
df2
| res | abmn   |
| 1   | 1234   |
| 0   | 1256   |
| 2   | 1267   |
```

I would want two dataframes only with

```
df1 
| res | abmn   |
| 3   | 1234   |
| 2   | 1256   |
df2
| res | abmn   |
| 1   | 1234   |
| 0   | 1256   |
```

I tried a loop but that wouldn't work since they are of different lengths. I think I managed to have a list with all the strings of the abmn values (all values that are in all four datasets) but I haven't really found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible answer to your question. I first see which values are common to both, and then create two **new dataframes** based on the values to keep.

Here is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd

# generate the dataframes as per the example
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"res":[3,0,2], "abmn":[1234,1245,1256]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"res":[1,0,2], "abmn":[1234,1256,1267]})

# identify the items to keep
items_to_keep = []
for item in df1['abmn']:
    if item in df2['abmn'].values:
        items_to_keep.append(item)
   
# create new dataframes based on the list of items to keep
new_df1 = df1[df1.abmn.isin(items_to_keep)]
new_df2 = df2[df2.abmn.isin(items_to_keep)]

# print the two new dataframes
print("new_df1")
print(new_df1)
print("==========")
print("new_df2")
print(new_df2)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
new_df1
   res  abmn
0    3  1234
2    2  1256
==========
new_df2
   res  abmn
0    1  1234
1    0  1256
```

**Please note**, that the for-loop, can be replaced with a list-comprehension:

```
# identify the items to keep
items_to_keep = [item for item in df1['abmn'] if item in df2['abmn'].values]
```